# 100% Homebuilt Airplane

Tags: airplane, homebuilt

[image]
THIS IS JUST A SIMULATION OF THE INTENDED AILERON THAT I'LL BUILD AND PUT ON MY HOMEMEADE PLANE.(I scrampled all the materials I could find in my backyard).
Do you find any abnormality in this aileron in relation to the aileron on real planes('cos I have never really seen the aileron setup of a real plane)

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Looks like you have the basics of the wing mounted control horn down.  Maybe change the aileron connections (both ends of the threaded rod) to a ball & socket setup so there is no 'slop' in the control from a rod in a hole; don't want any fluttering from loose connections.

Comment: Your control link to the aileron will fail in compression from buckling long before the expected flight loads are reached. Try to use tubes, not rods.

Comment: Okay thank you so much  Peter @PeterKampf

Answer (score 2):

For a non-working prototype it doesn't look *too* bad - you have a bell crank connected to a control arm that's attached to the aileron.

However, the devil is in the details and messing up a detail **can kill you**.

- You will want to use acceptable materials and construction techniques (See [AC 43.13](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/74417)).
- You need to ensure the bell crank is the right size so the control forces are correct (neither too big or too small).
- You need to ensure the aileron is the right size and shape and travels the correct amount.
- You need to ensure your hinges are of sufficient quality (hardware store stuff will break and **can kill you**) and are attached to the wing safely (losing an aileron **can kill you**)
- You need to ensure your aileron isn't subject to [flutter](https://www.wired.com/2010/03/flutter-testing-aircraft/) (which **can kill you**)

If you haven't already, contact the [EAA](http://www.eaa.org) and get as heavily involved as possible.  They have an incredible amount of information available about how to safely design and build an airplane from the runway up.

Comment: Can any of that kill you?

Comment: Okay Thanks A lot @Dan Pichelman

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what specific feedback you are looking for here, but if the question is "will this work?" or "is this a good idea?" Then the answer is probably not. If you never built a plane before and have never even seen the design before, just making it up as you go is not a good idea. If this is a toy remote control plane, then you could get away with it. But if you intend for a person to fly in this, then you do not want to do this. For your first plane buy a kit, or at least get plans/blueprints for a proven design. Once you know how these things work, then maybe start improvising a little by modifying existing designs. Sorry to rain on your parade but I think you are taking risks that you do not need to take.

Comment: Okay,thanks Dan